# npm3 install breaks the flat structure if installing module from local folder

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

I have the following dependency tree:

```
module_a@1.9.15
    module_b@1.0.22
    module_c@1.1.2 
        module_b@1.0.22
```

(The important part is that module_b is a dependency of both module_a and module_c)

Now when I create the initial npm install (npm3) it will be resolved correctly using only one instance of module_b in a flat manner:

```
module_a@1.9.15
    module_b@1.0.22
    module_c@1.1.2
```

Now I want to reinstall module_b from local folder after changing some code to be able to test it quickly (without having to push module_b into the registry). So I do the following:

```
npm install ../module_b
```

(module_b resides locally in the same folder as module_a)

But when I do this unfortunately the flat structure breaks and the module structure looks like this:

```
module_a@1.9.15 /home/gsanta/
├── module_b@1.0.22  invalid
├─┬ module_c@1.1.2
│ └── module_b@1.0.22
```

Why is it working this way? I'm still using the same version of module_b (1.0.22) just installed it from local folder.

How does npm determine if two dependent modules are the same version (it looks like it's not the version field in package.json)?